# DLL on system32 folder on of winforms software

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield

I've developed a C# windows forms program, and I'm using the Install Shield delivered with the visual studio to make the installation process. The software generate many dependencies (dlls) in  the release folder. What I want to do is:

I want to install some of these dependencies in the system32 or some windows dlls folder instead of letting it all in the installation folder.

I'm a little newbie with the IS and I'm not figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Don't do that.  .Net's assembly resolver will load your dependencies; you should leave them where they are.  Do not pollute the Windows folder.

Comment: I'm guessing you're unfamiliar with the phrase "DLL Hell"?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the concept dll hell, what could it be?

Comment: Should I just copy the dlls to a bin folder of my program instead? how can I do this without lose the references?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it - especially if you are writing a managed program. The .net dependency loader will take care of this for you, there is no problem with having your dlls in the application's directory.

However, if they have a strong name (ie. libraries from third party developers, who signed their work with a key) they can be installed in the GAC.

This will prevent the system directories from getting cluttered with dlls, possibly overwriting existing ones, thus breaking other programs.